# How did Hecke come up with Hecke-operators?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request, math-history, modular-forms

I'm currently studying Hecke-operators and I'm curious how Hecke came up with them. The original definition he gave in his paper is $$\left( f \mid T_n\right) (z) = n^{k - 1} \sum_{ad = n, \, b \mod d, \, d > 0} d^{-k } f\left( \frac{az + b}{d}\right)$$
for a modular form $f$ of weight $k$. This is an averaging over the set of representatives of the action of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ on $M_n := \left\{ A \in \mathbf{Z}^{2 \times 2} : \det (A) = n \right\}$ (acting by left-multiplication), i.e. $$f \mid T_n = n^{\frac{k}{2} - 1} \sum_{\alpha \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}) \text{ \ } M_n} f \mid_k \alpha$$
where $\mid_k$ is the slash-operator. But why would someone consider such an 'averaging'? Is there anything one can hope for by averaging over $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}) \text{ \ } M_n$?

More generally, why did Hecke consider operators of such kind?

Comment: How in the heck did Hecke come up with Hecke-operators.

Comment: Hecke extended earlier work of Hurwitz, who treated algebraic correspondences between modular curves which realise some individual Hecke operators. Also Mordell (1917) used Hecke operators on modular forms in a paper on the special cusp form of Ramanujan - before Hecke gave a general theory.

Comment: That's a heck of a question.

Comment: It is rather natural from $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n e^{2i \pi nz}$ to look at $f^{[m]}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n m} e^{2i \pi nmz}$. Hecke observed in some cases $f^{[m]}(z)$ is again modular for a smaller congruence subgroup, and wondered if he could add a term such that $f^{[m]}(z)$ stays in the same congruence subgroup, and that's what he found with $p^{k-1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n/p} e^{2i \pi nz/p}$ when $m=p$ is prime. Then extending by multiplicativity is  natural.

Comment: Also on the L-function side, removing an Euler factor from the Euler product makes (on the modular forms side) the eigenform modular for a smaller congruence subgroup. Again this is very natural, and leads to the Hecke operators.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't going to be a perfect answer and I'm not sure that it is what motivated Hecke (because I haven't read extensively enough), but I think a pretty nice of way of thinking about Hecke operators on modular forms is as follows.

First, we define a *lattice* $L \subset \mathbb{C}$ to be a subgroup $\mathbb{Z} \omega_1 +\mathbb{Z} \omega_2$, with $\omega_1, \omega_2$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$. We assume that $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is in the upper-half plane. Then we let $R$ be the free group over $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by all such lattices in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $S$ be the set of all lattices in $\mathbb{C}$.

Next, for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we define a *weight $k$ lattice function* to be a function $F: S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ satisfying a homogeneity condition: that is  $F(\lambda L) = \lambda^{-k} F(L)$ for all $L \in S, \lambda \in \mathbb{C}^*$. Let the set of lattice functions of weight $k$ be $LF_k$.

Then it is not difficult to see the following: that there is a bijection between suitable lattice functions of weight $k$ and modular forms of weight $k$ given by the following:

$$ \sigma: f \in M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z})) \mapsto (\mathbb{Z} \omega_1 +\mathbb{Z} \omega_2 \mapsto \omega_2^{-k} f(\omega_1/\omega_2)) \in LF_{k}$$
where $\omega_1/\omega_2$ is in the upper-half plane

$$\tau: F \in LF_{k} \mapsto (z \mapsto F(\mathbb{Z}z+\mathbb{Z})) \in M_k(SL_2(\mathbb{Z}))$$

You need to check these are well-defined (i.e. that $\sigma$ is independent of the choice of $\omega_1, \omega_2$ and that $\sigma, \tau$ are mutually inverse). With this in mind, we make the following two definitions:

- For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $T(n): R \rightarrow R; L \mapsto \sum_{\substack{L' \subset L \\ [L:L']=n}}L'$ by the level $n$ Hecke operator
- For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let $R(n):= L \mapsto nL$

These seem like relatively simple, fairly natural functions to consider on lattices - they are probably the simplest two such functions we could think of on $R$. You may show without too much difficulty the following properties of $T, R$:

1. If $gcd(n,m)=1$ then $T(m)T(n)=T(nm)=T(n)T(m)$
2. If $p$ is prime and $r \geq 1$ then $T(p^r)T(p)=T(p^{r+1})+pR(p)T(p^{r-1})$

Now we can try to make a definition of the Hecke operator of a weight $k$ lattice function $F$ as follows:

$$ T(n)(F) : L \mapsto \sum_{\substack{L' \subset L \\ [L:L']=n}}F(L') $$

However, this doesn't turn out to be quite the right definition - we need some kind of extra scaling factor in front of the sum so that things turn out nicely. So we make the following definition:

$$ T(n)(F) : L \mapsto n^{k-1}\sum_{\substack{L' \subset L \\ [L:L']=n}}F(L') $$

Now, where does this $n^{k-1}$ come from? Well, if we rearrange our sum a bit we can show that due to the homogeneity of $F$ that

$$ T(n)(F) : L \mapsto \frac{1}{n}\sum_{\substack{L \subset L'' \\ [L'':L]=n}}F(L'') $$

So this Hecke operator really is averaging in some sense the images of $F$. Going to back to the previous description of $T(n)(F)$, if we make use of the bijection afforded to us by $\sigma$, then we can try to describe $T(n)(f)$ by computing $T(n)(\sigma(f))$ as a lattice function and then changing it back to a modular form.

For this, we use that the sublattices $L' \subset L$ of $L$ of index $n$ are in bijection with matrices $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{array}\right) \in GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ with $ad=n$ and $0 \leq b \leq d-1$. IF $L=\mathbb{Z} \omega_1 +\mathbb{Z} \omega_2$, then the $L'$ corresponding to $\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{array}\right)$ will be $L=\mathbb{Z} (a\omega_1+b\omega_2) +\mathbb{Z} d\omega_2$.

Putting all of the above together we conclude that $\tau(T(n)(\sigma(f)))$ has the form described by Hecke in his paper. This is the definition we take then for the Hecke operators of modular forms.

This has a useful description of all this with all the proofs: [Stein & Ribet](http://wstein.org/books/ribet-stein/main.pdf)

When we try to study something with a nice rich mathematical structure, morphisms of those structures are often the best way to approach things. Hopefully the above is convincing enough that the Hecke operators as morphisms are fairly natural morphisms to consider when we speak about Hecke operators. They have all kinds of special significance, but that one that comes to mind most immediately for me is that all of the Eisentstein series are going to be eigenforms - that is they are eigenvectors for each Hecke operator. That's a pretty stunning property.

Comment: I think that historically they were made to try and get at the Fourier coefficients of modular forms as an averaging process--precisely the same way that one tries to get at Fourier coefficients of $L^2$-functions in $S^1$ (by Poisson summation). Who knows though? At the end of the day it's just the $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}^f_\mathbb{Q})$-action on the cohomology of $\displaystyle \varprojlim X(N)$ anways :P

Comment: PS, I think this perspective is also explained, if the OP wanted to read more in this vein, in Calegari's review of Diamond and Shurman.

Comment: Of course, that makes sense - at least partially, I don't know a terribly great deal about all of this.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I know your comment was 4 years ago but can you point me to a source that elucidates how you get the Fourier coefficients using Hecke operators? I can't find this review by Calegari you mention.

Comment: @JPhy This is the review iirc, https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2006-43-03/S0273-0979-06-01098-6/S0273-0979-06-01098-6.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think of Hecke operators when interpreted as double coset operators as solving a relatively easy question in representation theory. For simplicity let $G$ be a finite group and $M$ be a complex vector space on which $G$ acts from the right. For similarity with modular forms let's denote the action of $g \in G$ on $m \in M$ by $m_{| g}$. Let $G_1,G_2$ be subgroups of $G$ and $M_i := M^{G_i}$ the subspace of elements invariant under $G_i$.

To get the analogue with hecke operators one actually needs $G=GL_2^+(\mathbb Q)$ the matrices with positive determinant and $M$ to be the holomorphic functions on the (extended) upper half plane with the $|_k$ action and $G_1$ and $G_2$ to be congruence subgroups of $G$. So that $M_i = M_k(G_i)$.  In this case the finiteness conditions on G is not satisfied, but one can work around this with some effort using the congruence subgroup property of $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Now the group ring $\mathbb C[G]$ gives a large source of linear operators on $M$. I.e. map $\mathbb C[G] \to Hom_{\mathbb C}(M, M)$ given by $\sum_G a_g g \mapsto (m \mapsto \sum_G a_g m_{|g})$.  And one can ask the question if we can use these operators in $\mathbb C[G]$ to get linear maps in  $Hom_{\mathbb C}(M_1,M_2)$. The first thing to notice is that elements in $M_1$ are invariant under $G_1$ so if $m_1 \in M_1$ $g \in G$ and $g_1 \in G_1$ then $m_1g_1g = m_1g$. In parcticular  $a_g {m_1}_{|g}$ only depends on its equivealence class in $\mathbb C[G_1\backslash G ]$. So we get a map $\mathbb C[G_1\backslash G ] \to Hom_{\mathbb C}(M_1, M)$. In order for $m_1 \mapsto a_g {m_1}_{|g}$ to actually to give a map $Hom_{\mathbb C}(M_1, M_2)$ we additionally need $a_g {m_1}_{|g} \in M_2$. One way to achieve this is to make sure that $\sum a_g (G_1g)$ is invariant under $G_2$, i.e. $\sum a_g (G_1g) \in \mathbb C[G_1\backslash G]^{G_2}$. Now if $O$ is an orbit of $G_1\backslash G$ under $G_2$ then $\sum_{g \in O} G_1g$ is in $\mathbb C[G_1\backslash G]^{G_2}$. And in fact the elements of the form $\sum_{g \in O} G_1g$ form a basis for $\mathbb C[G_1\backslash G]^{G_2}$. However the orbits of $G_1\backslash G$ under $G_2$ are easily identified with elements of $G_1\backslash G / G_2$ i.e. the double cosets.

So one of the reason to consider such averaging is that after applying an operator to a modular form of weight $k$ you want to end up with a modular form of weight $k$ again, and not an arbitrary holomorphic function on the upper half plane. This averaging operation, together with the fact that the set $M_n$ is invariant from the left and the right under $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$ ensure that hecke operators send modular forms to modular forms again.